# Command line parameters for SQL Server 2008 R2 silent installations gets ignored

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, silent-installer

In our InstallShield project we install a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with parameter as silent.

In about 99% of the cases everything works, the installation runs.

But at at least at one customer PC we from time to time have problems. This time we have the behavior that the SQL Setup ignores the given parameters, during installation the SQL setup wants that the user will configure everything. Our InstallShield setup waits normally.

(The customer has a French Windows XP with SP3).

The only strange thing we found in the log files are that its written "re-launching setup.exe from". A local setup will be used. Bug this setup has the same version we need and we are not able to reproduce.

Any idea when this is caused?

That's the command line we have configured in the InstallShield project:

```
/QS /Action=Install /Hideconsole /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
/SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /InstanceName=OurName 
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
/ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" 
/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SECURITYMODE=SQL 
/SAPWD=NobodyCares /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True 
/TCPENABLED=1 /ENABLERANU=True
```

Comment: nobody have an idea?

Comment: http://www.installationdeveloper.com/1704/using-localized-account-names-to-install-sql-server-2008-express/

Answer (score 0):

Search the error in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log folder\summary.txt;

Probably the group administrators have another name in french;

We have same problem in portuguese;

(PS: sorry bad english )